# Probability that cubic of integer ends with 11

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let $x$ be an integer between $1$ and $10^{12}$. What is the probability that $x^3$ ends with 11?

I started with expressing $x^3=(a+10b)^3$ and applied binomial theorem to get $$x^3 = a^3+300b^2a+30a^2b+1000b^3 $$
How do I proceed from here?
Thanks.

Comment: Which of the terms in the expansion do not influence the last two digits of the cube?

Comment: @DanielFischer $300b^2a$ and $1000b^3$ don't affect the last two digits, correct?

Comment: Right. And $30a^2b$ doesn't affect the last. So we need $a^3$ to end with $1$. Which values of $a$ does that leave?

Comment: 3 is prime to both 2 and 5, which has implications for how the terminal-digit patterns of cubes are distributed.

Comment: In the first hundred there is just $71$ who cubed gives $357911$. This repeats every hundred. The probability is $1\%$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already noticed that only $a^3$ and $30a^2b$ affect the last two digits.

Notice further that only $a^3$ affects the final digit--namely, the final digit of $x^3$ *is* the final digit of $a^3.$ Thus, $a=1.$

Consequently, the second-to-last digit of $x^3$ is the last digit of $3b,$ and so we need the last digit of $b$ to be $7.$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Except $9^3 = \cdots9$.

Comment: @WADon: I appreciate the heads-up! I was thinking of squares, rather than cubes. Should be fixed now!

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Comment: @Forumwhiner: I just noticed an error. It should be fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

If $x^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 100$, then $x^2 x \equiv 1$ and so $x$ is a unit mod $100$.
The group of units mod $100$ has order $\phi(100)=40$.
Therefore, since $\gcd(40,3)=1$, the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection.
Thus, there is exactly one $x$ such that $x^3 \equiv 11 \bmod 100$.

Comment: I don't completely follow: 71^3, 171^3, 271^3, etc all equivalent to 11 mod 100

Comment: @zcahgg1, sure, it's unique only mod 100.

Comment: @zcahgg1 that's 1/100 probability right there, i.e. for every 100 numbers, you'll have 1 number hitting that `11 mod 1000`, hence the probability is 1/100